# Ajax POST to Cakephp Controller always give array() result

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

i really struggle to get the POST value in the controller .i am really new to this..Please someone share me some light..being in the dark for long hours now.
i had a checkboxes and need to pass all the ids that had been checked to the controller and use that ids to update my database.i don't know what did i did wrong, tried everything and some examples too like here:
 [sending data via ajax in Cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17504604/sending-data-via-ajax-in-cakephp)

found some question about same problem too , but not much helping me( or maybe too dumb to understand) . i keep getting array();

please help me..with my codes or any link i can refer to .here my codes: 
my view script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.checkall:button').toggle(function(){
    $('input:checkbox').attr('checked','checked');

    $('#button').click( function (event) {  

      var memoData = [];
      $.each($("input[name='memo']:checked"), function(){            
        memoData.push($(this).val());
      });
      var value = memoData.join(", ")
      //alert("value are: " + value);  

      //start
      $.ajax({
        type:"POST", 
        traditional:true;
        data:{value_to_send:data_to_send}, 
        url:"../My/deleteAll/",
        success : function(data) {
        alert(value);// will alert "ok"

     },
     error : function() {
       alert("false submission fail");
     }
     });
      //end

      } ); //end of button click
  },function(){//uncheck
    $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');


  });

});
```

my controller :

```
public function deleteAll(){
if( $this->request->is('POST') ) {
 // echo $_POST['value_to_send'];
 //echo   $value = $this->request->data('value_to_send');

 //or 
    debug($this->request->data);exit;

}

}
```

and result of this debug is:

```
\app\Controller\MyController.php (line 73)

array()
```

Please help me.Thank you so much

Comment: You write in ajax `data:{value_to_send:data_to_send}, `, Are you putting `data_to_send` the `value`? Where `var value = memoData.join(", ")`;

Comment: oh sorry about that, it supposed to be a data:{value_to_send:value}. i was playing around with the codes before. but still the problem is there. everytime i debug, its look like there's nothing have been pass to the controller...:(

Comment: Have you tried this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37474208/ajax-post-to-cakephp-controller-always-give-array-result/37476320#37476320)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.checkall:button').toggle(function() {

        $('input:checkbox').attr('checked','checked');

        $('#button').click(function(event) {  

            var memoData = [];

            $.each($("input[name='memo']:checked"), function(){            
                memoData.push($(this).val());
            });

            //start
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST', 
                url: '../My/deleteAll/',
                data: {value_to_send: memoData}, 

                success : function(data) {
                    alert(data);// will alert "ok"

                },
                error : function() {
                    alert("false submission fail");
                }
            });//end ajax

        }); //end of button click

    },function(){//uncheck

        $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');

    });

});
```

In controller:

```
public function deleteAll()
{
    $this->autoRender = false;      

    if($this->request->is('Ajax')) { //<!-- Ajax Detection

        $elements = explode(",", $_POST['value_to_send']);

        foreach($elements as $element)
        {
            //find and delete
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: hello sir, Thank you so mch for helping me.i try your solution and with the couple of modification on the codes, i manage to get those data passed to my controller. But i have some question to ask , how can i do the find and delete on the foreach($elements as $element)? . i am sorry, i really lost when its come to this.Thanks again

Comment: The best way would be to pass ids (`$elements = ['1','3','6',...]`) and then only you would have to search by id. 
`$post = $this->Posts->get($element)`
If it´s not, then just find element by some thing e.g: 'name'
`$post = $this->Posts->find()->where(['name' => $element])->first()`
Now you can delete element.
`$this->Posts->delete($post)`

Comment: Thank you so much sir for helping me to understand this. after fixing and modified the code as needed, i manage to get it work :)

Comment: @winwizardy I`m glad to help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the data type as json in ajax call

JQUERY CODE:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "../My/deleteAll/",
  type: "POST",
  dataType:'json',
  data:{value_to_send:data_to_send}, 
  success: function(data){

  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, i tried this, but somehow its still gave me an error." false submission fail". when i debug with chrome i catch this error : `message
:
"Unexpected token i in JSON at position 0"` . so tried the solution above and modified a bit and it goes ok without problem.